# App keeps stopping after I add a email Verification button

Tags: java, android

My application Keeps stopping after I add the Verify Email button. My Email Verification and Application is working correctly before I adding the verify Email Address button. I have included the Logcat and Source code of both xml and Java

Here is the Java code:

```
package com.dev.hospital;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FirebaseAuth fAuth;
Button resendCode;
TextView verifyMsg;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    verifyMsg.findViewById(R.id.verifymsg);
    resendCode.findViewById(R.id.resendcode);
    fAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    FirebaseUser user = fAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if(!user.isEmailVerified()) {
        resendCode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        verifyMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        resendCode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                FirebaseUser users = fAuth.getCurrentUser();
                users.sendEmailVerification().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Verification Email Has Been Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Log.d("TAGS","onFailure: Email not sent" + e.getMessage());
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    }
}
//Logout function
public void logout(View view) {
    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),login.class));
    finish();
} }
```

It shows the warning: Null pointer exception in the module isEmailVerified()

Here is my XML code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/backgroundmain"
android:clickable="false"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<TextView
    android:onClick="logout"
    android:id="@+id/logout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/font"
    android:text="@string/logout"
    android:textColor="@color/textcolormain"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.898"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.052" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/verifymsg"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/font"
    android:text="Email not Verified!"
    android:textColor="#ff0000"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.888" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/resendcode"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/shapes"
    android:fontFamily="@font/font"
    android:text="Verify Now"
    android:textColor="@color/textColor"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.535"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" 
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.976" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Here is my Logcat: Shows error in onCreate: MainActivity.Java:24

```
2020-05-06 21:12:56.156 4930-4930/com.dev.hospital E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dev.hospital, PID: 4930
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity    ComponentInfo{com.dev.hospital/com.dev.hospital.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.TextView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2725)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6261)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1064)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.widget.TextView.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.dev.hospital.MainActivity.onCreate**(MainActivity.java:24)**
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6705)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2678)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2790) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:203) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6261) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1064) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:925)
```

Comment: `verifyMsg.findViewById(R.id.verifymsg);` – That's not how to use `findViewById()`. You want to assign `findViewById()`'s return to your `TextView` variable; e.g., `verifyMsg = findViewById(R.id.verifymsg);`. And similarly everywhere else you use it.

Comment: Consider switching to view binding instead of using findViewById